# applying a uniqueness constraint across group of records

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I'm trying to design a data model where we need to enforce uniqueness *across* groups of records, but duplicates are *allowed* within a single group.

Business Context:

- We have two main models, `User` and `Account`
- `User` owns multiple `Accounts` in a 1..N relationship
- `Account` has a few properties like `email`, `phone_number`, etc.

We want to enforce that certain fields in the `Account` (e.g. `email` and `phone_number`) are unique across users, i.e. each `Account.email`/`Account.phone_number` belong to at most one `User`. It is required that a user can own two accounts with the same email.

First, how can we define this constraint? Second, how do we manage this constraint? I'm wondering how it will be possible to insert `Account` and handle duplicates. Furthermore, I'm wondering how we will be able to handle deletes, specifically, deleting the `Account` that owns the last `email` for the `User` should free it up for other users to claim.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think most developers would just leave it up to the application to enforce this. That's risky because applications can have bugs and fail to enforce it properly, or get into race conditions. But that's how most developers do it, even with the imperfections.

To do this properly and make the database enforce it, you'd create a third table `Emails`, so you could record each distinct email, and designate which user it belongs to.

```
CREATE TABLE Emails (
  email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (email),
  KEY (user_id, email),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(id)
);
```

This gives a 1:1 relationship from users to emails. Each email defines which user owns it, therefore a given email cannot be used by more than one user. But it still allows a user to have more than one email, if that's desired.

Then you make sure your Accounts table references an entry in the index of that table:

```
CREATE TABLE Account (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id, email) REFERENCES Email (user_id, email)
);
```

Thus you have a 1..N relationship from a single email to multiple accounts. Each account may use only an email that is owned by the respective user.